# Espresso NoMatchingViewException

Tags: android, gradle, android-espresso

I'm trying to create my first Espresso test class and have a problem with it. 
I have been reading official [samples](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing/tree/master/ui/espresso/BasicSample)  and make analogy class.

```
package name.xunicorn.iocipherbrowserext.app;



import android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule;
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;
import name.xunicorn.iocipherbrowserext.R;
import name.xunicorn.iocipherbrowserext.activities.MainActivity;

import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import static android.support.test.espresso.Espresso.onView;

import static android.support.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.matches;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.isDisplayed;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withId;

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class DefaultFragmentTest {
    public final static String TAG = "DefaultFragmentTest";

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityRule =
            new ActivityTestRule<MainActivity>(MainActivity.class);

    @Test
    public void defaultFragment_isLoaded() {
        onView(withId(R.id.btnPlug)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    }

    @Test
    public void defaultFragment_plugButtonClick() {
        onView(withId(R.id.btnPlug)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));

    }
}
```

In main activity, I'm creating fragment and put ut to `FrameLayout`. What i cannot understand that's why one of this tests case always passed and another throws `NoMatchingViewException`? Could someone explain me that?

My gradle:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'name.xunicorn.iocipherbrowserext'
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "0.0.5"

    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'

    compile 'info.guardianproject.iocipher:IOCipherStandalone:0.3'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.jaredrummler:android-device-names:1.0.8'
    compile "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1"

    // Testing-only dependencies
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.4.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.4.1'
    // Optional -- Hamcrest library
    androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'
    // Optional -- UI testing with Espresso
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1'

}
```

Comment: -how does the test flow looks like when you observe it on the phone, do you see the activity starting 2 times?
-what is the full stacktrace
-how does your code look like?

Comment: is the question still relevant? if so pls provide the log output and the layout where the test fails

Comment: if the view you need to test stays inside the fragment you'll need to wait until the fragment has been replaced in your FrameLayout before accessing it from your test.